# Bitshares - Boost libraries could not be found

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I've been following this guide: https://github.com/bitshares/bitshares-core

**My Setup:**

- OS: WIndows 10 64 bit
- Cmake v3.8.0
- Boost v1.60.0

When running this command: cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo . I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:1129 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.60.0

  Boost include path: C:/local/boost_1_60_0

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_thread
          boost_date_time
          boost_system
          boost_filesystem
          boost_program_options
          boost_signals
          boost_serialization
          boost_chrono
          boost_unit_test_framework
          boost_context
          boost_locale
          boost_iostreams

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  libraries/fc/CMakeLists.txt:116 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Using custom FindBoost.cmake
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:495 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.60.0;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:497 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = ON
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:499 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:501 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME =
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:503 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS =
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:505 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS =
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:557 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:559 ]   BOOST_ROOT = C:\local\boost_1_60_0
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:561 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = C:\local\boost_1_60_0\include
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:563 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = C:\local\boost_1_60_0\lib
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:565 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.60.0;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:658 ] location of version.hpp: C:/local/boost_1_60_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:682 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.60.0
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:758 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER =
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:768 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:811 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:813 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:862 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = C:\local\boost_1_60_0\lib;C:\local\boost_1_60_0/lib;C:\local\boost_1_60_0/stage/lib;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/../lib;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/../lib/;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:950 ] Searching for COROUTINE_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_coroutine-mt-1_60;libboost_coroutine-mt;libboost_coroutine-mt-1_60;libboost_coroutine-mt;libboost_coroutine;libboost_coroutine-mt-s-1_60;libboost_coroutine-mt-s;libboost_coroutine-mt-s-1_60;libboost_coroutine-mt-s
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:986 ] Searching for COROUTINE_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_coroutine-mt-gd-1_60;libboost_coroutine-mt-gd;libboost_coroutine-mt-gd-1_60;libboost_coroutine-mt-gd;libboost_coroutine-mt;libboost_coroutine;libboost_coroutine-mt-s-gd-1_60;libboost_coroutine-mt-s-gd;libboost_coroutine-mt-s-gd-1_60;libboost_coroutine-mt-s-gd
-- [ C:/Users/Carl/Documents/bitshares/bitshares-core/libraries/fc/CMakeModules/FindBoost.cmake:1037 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
```

I tried manually setting Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS to OFF inside the .cmake file or via command line but it did not work for me.

The directories specified on the `BOOST_ROOT`, `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` are existing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hope that  you are in the Correct Directory ,that is where bitshare-core is downloaded

Comment: Yes, I am running cmake command from the root directory of bitshares-core

Comment: Let me check at my side

Comment: Try this Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE to ON

Comment: @ATulSingh I am still getting the same error above when using Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE  ON.

Comment: Boost is currently searched by find_package of cmake  
Ln : 180 FindBoost.cmake  .Cmake is not able to identify Boost Properly , May be you can use a different version of Boost or experiment with different options of find_package instead of QUITE so that error can be seen

Comment: I think it is currently using find_package of Bitshares' custom FindBoost.cmake

Comment: find_package is working  as its is able to FindBoost but problem is in finding Boost Components.

Comment: On the CMakeLists.txt, there is FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.60 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${BOOST_COMPONENTS}). Anyway, I'll try installing another Boost version and see if it works.

Comment: I just tried Boost v1.56.0 but still getting the same error.

Comment: Which **exact** file under `C:\local\boost_1_60_0\lib` corresponds to `boost_coroutine` library? Check that this file (without extension) is contained in the list specified in the line `Searching for COROUTINE_LIBRARY_RELEASE`.

Comment: I have `libboost_coroutine-vc140-mt-gd-1_60` under `C:\local\boost_1_60_0\lib`. all my libboost libraries have the -`vc140`extension

Comment: Suffix `-vc140` means that your Boost installation is for *Visual Studio 2015* (see [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42068050/3440745) about such suffixes). That installation can be used with `Visual Studio 14 2015` [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) in CMake. Check that you use exactly this generator. (Generator name is printed at the beginning of the configuration process).